# How to hide my platform from a browser to keep my privacy?

Tags: privacy, web-browser, javascript, tracking

I just visited https://amiunique.org/fp in order to try to understand what makes a web page realize what platform it is running on, aside from `User-Agent` request header.

So I learned about `window.navigator`, which has member `platform` and more that are used to track me.

My question is how can I change these values in my PC and phone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I spoof my user agent so that the type of device I'm using doesn't show up?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/180076), [How do I hide the OS I am using from internet sites?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/173233), [How to fight browser fingerprinting?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23053), [Defeating Browser Fingerprinting by spoofing the browser user agent...](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91166/), [How can I manipulate the browser fingerprint?](https://superuser.com/questions/894647) and more.

Answer (score 1):

It's virtually impossible to do this on your own. There are *dozens* of fingerprinting vectors that can be used to detect the operating system you are running or uniquely identify a browser, and sometimes even your individual hardware irrespective of the OS you use. Paradoxically, any changes you make to your browser configuration actually make this *worse*. In addition, TCP option fingerprinting makes it such that your browser alone is incapable of hiding the platform you are using, because the mere connection that comes from your operating system leaks the operating system (and even system uptime).

There is *a* solution, however, which is to use Tor Browser on the highest security setting. Every Tor Browser installation attempts to be indistinguishable from each other (it has a large *anonymity set*). It's not perfect, but it's far better than nothing. The use of Tor as a proxy also defeats TCP fingerprinting.

Comment: I was thinking about it for a bit, maybe I can rent a VM somewhere and use RDP from my phone.. Or can the website recognize that as well? I find it hard to believe though.

Comment: @W2a It will likely fingerprint the VPS in that case.